# Replace NA values by string "Unknown" in R

Tags: r

I have a list X that contains the 12 months in a year. In my data, I have a column Y that has the following levels: "Done", "Not Done" and "". I want to replace the "" by the string "Unknown".

I tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(X)) {
   X[[i]]$Y[which(is.na(X[[i]]$Y))] == "Unknown"
}
```

I get the error:

> "Error: unexpected input in " 
>   PList15[[i]]$IB.Opportunity.Type[which(is.na(PList15[[i]]$IB.Opportunity))]
>   == "Unknown"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example showing desired result.

Comment: Why not simple  X[is.na(X)] <- "Unknown" ..

Answer (score 1):

Since Y is a factor, you could do:

```
levels(X$Y)[levels(X$Y)==""] <- "unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for this, you can do it like:

```
# Some data with `""`
v <- 1:10
v[c(3,5,8)] <- ""
v
 [1] "1"  "2"  ""   "4"  ""   "6"  "7"  ""   "9"  "10"


v[v == ""] <- "Unknown"

 [1] "1"       "2"       "Unknown" "4"       "Unknown" "6"       "7"       "Unknown" "9"       "10"
```

Comment: thank you for the code, however I need a loop since I have 12 months in the List X? It does not work if I write: X[[i]]$Y [X[[i]]$Y == ""] = "Unknown"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, then we can try to find a solution